# Extending good covers of $\partial M$ to $M$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold with boundary with a free action of a finite group $G$. Suppose one has an equivariant collar $c: \partial M \times [0,1) \rightarrow M$. An open cover is equivariant if the collection is closed under the group action. An open cover is good if all finite intersections are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is it true that any equivariant good cover of $\operatorname{im}(c)$ is extendable to all of $M$ (perhaps after cutting the collar in half)? I am happy to assume that $M$ is smooth, but I would not like to assume the collar is.